# JavaScript - Simple If inside For

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

Having an issue with the following as I learn JS basics. My If was working before I stuck it inside the For, but now nothing seems to be working. Thought about doing forEach but seems like a complex solution for such a simple problem (creating another function to run forEach with). Also been running it through online code checkers and it is coming back clean.

Hoping I'm doing something ignorant like misaligned tabs..

```js
"use strict";

function scan(inputArray) {

  var count = 0,
    iter = 0,
    len = inputArray.length;

  for (iter = 0; iter < len; iter + 1) {

    console.log("inside for: " + iter); //diagnostic line, does not display

    if (inputArray[iter] === "contraband") {
      console.log("inside if: " + iter); //diagnostic line, does not display
      count += 1;
    } //end if

  } //end for

  return count;

} //end function -scan-

// Test Code
const numItems = scan(['contraband', 'dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers', 'contraband']);
console.log('Number of "contraband": ' + numItems); // should be 3
```

Comment: Your for loop condition is reversed(it should be `iter < len`)

Comment: Ah! That is very helpful, thought that parameter was 'until true' rather than 'while true'; now the loop is endlessly repeating, I'm going to check it over again

Comment: Missed the second mistake on my initial review; in the for loop update condition, you never actually update `iter`, so it should be `iter = iter  + 1`, or `iter++`.

Comment: AhKay, so iter + 1 is not the same as iter = iter +1 or iter++

Comment: Yeah, iter +1 doesn't actually change `iter`'s value

Comment: @sm7x Why would you expect `iter + 1` to change `iter`? It can be used in a variety of contexts, e.g. `other_variable = iter + 1`.

Comment: @Barmar my assumption was that the 'update condition' was only asking 'what do you want to do with the variable you declared two semicolons ago, after we complete a loop?' and thus I told it 'iter + 1'

Comment: There's no requirement that there be a variable declared there, and you can also declare multiple variables. It's not "what do you want to do with that variable", it's just "what do you want to do after each eteration"

Comment: I understand how you have explained it there, I appreciate your help with my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a for loop you need to have 3 statements, which are:

Statement 1 -- is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block;

Statement 2 -- defines the condition for executing the code block;

Statement 3 -- is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

The reason why your code is not working is that you had a mistake in the 3rd statement, where you wrote `iter + 1`, without really changing the value of `iter`. What you had to do is write in the 3rd statement `iter = iter + 1` OR `iter += 1` OR `iter++`, and all of these change the value of `iter` to +1.

The for loop should be like this:

```
for(iter = 0; iter < len; iter++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

- the iter variable should be less than length of the array
- The iter should be incremented to make the access to  elemenst of the array.

```js
"use strict";

function scan(inputArray) {

  var count = 0,
    iter = 0,
    len = inputArray.length;

  for (iter = 0; iter < len; iter++) {

    console.log("inside for: " + iter); //diagnostic line, does not display

    if (inputArray[iter] === "contraband") {
      console.log("inside if: " + iter); //diagnostic line, does not display
      count += 1;
    } //end if

  } //end for

  return count;

} //end function -scan-

// Test Code
const numItems = scan(['contraband', 'dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers', 'contraband']);
console.log('Number of "contraband": ' + numItems); // should be 3
```

Comment: This works! I just am not seeing what is different. When the > flipped to < for me my loop went infinitely at 0 iter... The only difference I see here is the var declarations on on each their own line?

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong and how you fixed it, not just dump code and challenge everyone to find the differences.

Comment: This corrected code, along with the comment thread on the original post is helping to clarify my misunderstandings, thanks for your role in this lesson!

Comment: @Barmar edited my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @smx Glad that this helped.